# MySQL for excel : Connection Attempt Failed. Getting this error in MS Excel

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, mysql-workbench, database-connection

[The error Message that I get when I double click my connection under local connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4So06.png)

I downloaded the MySQL for excel add-in for my excel. But whenever I double click on my connections in excel I get the following error: "Connection attempt failed. The given key was not present in the dictionary ". I tried uninstalling and reinstalling both my Microsoft office and MySQL but I am getting the same error no matter how often I try it. I'm completely new to programming and MySQL, and I am not able to find a solution to the problem that I am facing.

Comment: Could you please show the connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you currently using?

with 8.0.31 I've received the same error.
I've now installed 8.0.20 and now it's working.

Check my response from this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73536229/mysql-for-excel-error-the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary) for details.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33189380)