# mysql for excel error : "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

Tags: mysql, excel, database, error-handling, workbench

I would like to send Excel data to mysql database using mysql for Excel. But when I click Connection(any connection), An error appears:"The given key was not present in the dictionary"
how can i fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and just solve it today.

I used to have "MySQL Server Version: 8.0.31".
I've downgraded it to "8.0.20" and now it's working.

[MySQL Installer Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgQK4.png)

To downgrade it, I
(1) Removed the current MySQL Server Installation
(2) then i "Add" the new one, but explicitly selected "8.0.20"

[Version Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgQK4.png)

Be Aware!
When Deleting the MySQL Server, your current Databases will be removed. Make sure you have Backups / Exports of it.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you, @Capt BALU! Downgrading MySQL version works!

I've tested downgrading gradually, just to make sure to have the latest working version as possible. The latest one that stills work with "MySQL for Excel" add-in is **MySQL Server 8.0.28**.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34144149)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and couldn't find a solution, then I realized that where I developed my app was MariaDB 10.9.2, then in production they installed the MariaDB 11.1 version and I had the same error (as they are very similar databases). My solution was to downgrade my database engine. Try that, it might solve your problem.